# Put images in an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, children

At the moment, I have the code to put all my children of the "slides" class in an array in jQuery.

```
$('.slides').children().each(function (i) {
    var oImg = new Image();
    oImg.src = this.src;
    aImages.push(oImg);         
});
```

But now I heard that we have to use Javascript to create this.
All my attempts to recode the snippet from jQuery to Javascript have failed.
Does anybody know how to make it work?

Comment: Technically that *is* JavaScript. I assume you mean that you aren't allowed to use jQuery.

Comment: Well yeah. It's mostly the first line of code that is causing issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Get all the elements with class 'slides'
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('slides');

// Loop through all the elements first...
for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {

    // Get all the childNodes within each class 'slides'
    var children = elements[j].childNodes;

    // Loop through all the childrens
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var oImg = new Image();
        oImg.src = children[i].src;
        aImages.push(oImg);
    }
}
```

Comment: We're almost there, but apparently he can't find the variable children.
The developer tools of Chrome tell me this: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "lenght" of undefined"

Comment: Great! That solved it.
Stupid of myself that I didn't saw that the children variable wasn't a array

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
for(var i in elements){
  var childElements = elements[i].children;
  for(var j in childElements){
     var child = childElements[j];

     //your code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('slides');
    var myImages = elements.getElementsByTagName("img");

    for (var i = 0; i < myImages.length; i++) {
        var oImg = new Image();
        oImg.src = myImages[i].src;
        aImages.push(oImg);
    }
```

Comment: Stll an error: Uncaugght TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'getElementsByTagName'

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var aImages = [];

// get all elements with class slides
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slides');

// iterate through the slides array
for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    var slide = slides[0];

    // iterate through each child of slide
    for (var j = 0; i < slide.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var child = slide.childNodes[j];
        var oImg = new Image();
        oImg.src = this.src;
        aImages.push(oImg);
    }
}
```